# Implementing DDD (Red Book): Why did he made the Collaborators as Value Objects?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Im pertaining to the Red Book by Vaughn Vernon.

On the Collaboration Bounded Context he made the Author, Member, Participant, Creator etc as Value Objects where the fields are stored inline with the Entity they are bound to.

Lets say if you make a Discussion which has one Creator, then the fields of Creator (id, name, email) will be stored in the same table (tbl_discussions).

This is also true for the Forum. (see the schema below)

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS iddd_collaboration;
CREATE DATABASE iddd_collaboration;
USE iddd_collaboration;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_dispatcher_last_event` (
    `event_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_es_event_store` (
    `event_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `event_body` text NOT NULL,
    `event_type` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `stream_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `stream_version` int(11) NOT NULL,
    KEY (`stream_name`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`stream_name`, `stream_version`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_vw_calendar` (
    `calendar_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `description` varchar(500),
    `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `owner_email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `owner_identity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `owner_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `tenant_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    KEY `k_owner_identity` (`owner_identity`),
    KEY `k_tenant_id` (`name`,`tenant_id`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`calendar_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_vw_calendar_entry` (
    `calendar_entry_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `alarm_alarm_units` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `alarm_alarm_units_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `calendar_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `description` varchar(500),
    `location` varchar(100),
    `owner_email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `owner_identity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `owner_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `repetition_ends` datetime NOT NULL,
    `repetition_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `tenant_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `time_span_begins` datetime NOT NULL,
    `time_span_ends` datetime NOT NULL,
    KEY `k_calendar_id` (`calendar_id`),
    KEY `k_owner_identity` (`owner_identity`),
    KEY `k_repetition_ends` (`repetition_ends`),
    KEY `k_tenant_id` (`tenant_id`),
    KEY `k_time_span_begins` (`time_span_begins`),
    KEY `k_time_span_ends` (`time_span_ends`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`calendar_entry_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_vw_calendar_entry_invitee` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `calendar_entry_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `participant_email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `participant_identity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `participant_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `tenant_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    KEY `k_calendar_entry_id` (`calendar_entry_id`),
    KEY `k_participant_identity` (`participant_identity`),
    KEY `k_tenant_id` (`tenant_id`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_vw_calendar_sharer` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `calendar_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `participant_email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `participant_identity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `participant_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `tenant_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    KEY `k_calendar_id` (`calendar_id`),
    KEY `k_participant_identity` (`participant_identity`),
    KEY `k_tenant_id` (`tenant_id`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_vw_discussion` (
    `discussion_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `author_email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `author_identity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `author_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `closed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `exclusive_owner` varchar(100),
    `forum_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `tenant_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    KEY `k_author_identity` (`author_identity`),
    KEY `k_forum_id` (`forum_id`),
    KEY `k_tenant_id` (`tenant_id`),
    KEY `k_exclusive_owner` (`exclusive_owner`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`discussion_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_vw_forum` (
    `forum_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `closed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `creator_email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `creator_identity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `creator_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    `exclusive_owner` varchar(100),
    `moderator_email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `moderator_identity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `moderator_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `tenant_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    KEY `k_creator_identity` (`creator_identity`),
    KEY `k_tenant_id` (`tenant_id`),
    KEY `k_exclusive_owner` (`exclusive_owner`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`forum_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_vw_post` (
    `post_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `author_email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `author_identity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `author_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `body_text` text NOT NULL,
    `changed_on` datetime NOT NULL,
    `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
    `discussion_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `forum_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `reply_to_post_id` varchar(36),
    `subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `tenant_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    KEY `k_author_identity` (`author_identity`),
    KEY `k_discussion_id` (`discussion_id`),
    KEY `k_forum_id` (`forum_id`),
    KEY `k_reply_to_post_id` (`reply_to_post_id`),
    KEY `k_tenant_id` (`tenant_id`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now if the User change his email, then you have to update/synchronize all the tables to reflect the change.

Im just wondering why did he came up with that solution? What were the things he considered?

Also are there any alternative? Like achieving the same code, but persist them differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the book:

> There is not effort made to keep `Collborator` Value instances
>   synchronized with the *Identity and Access Context*. They are immutable
>   and can only be fully replaced, not modified. *p.468 para. 1*

That means synchronization will basically occur when the value will get replaced.

> If a `Collaborator` name or e-mail address changes in the *Identity
>   and Access Context*, such changes won't be automatically updated in
>   the *Collaboration Context*. Those kinds of changes rarely occur, so
>   the team made the decision to keep this particular design simple and
>   not attempt to sycnrhonize changes in the remote Context with objects
>   in their local Context. *p.469 para. 1*

You will also want to read out *`p.476 para.2 Can You Handle the Responsibility`*. In this section Vaughn demonstrates how complex it might be to keep data synchronized between bounded contexts when having to deal with out of order message consumption. It is also outlined that to guarantee the order of messages we may not rely on a complex messaging infrastructure but simply pull messages from the remote context (e.g. through a RESTful notification service<sup>2</sup>).

It's always a question of trade-offs and what is acceptable for your domain.

<sub>*2. Such approach is described at p.312 sec. Publishing Notifications as RESTful Resources.*</sub>

Comment: thank you for the reference. Cant believe Ive missed all these important details. I will read the whole chapter later and get back ;)

Comment: There is so much information in that book that it's more a reference book than a book you read once ;)

Comment: yeah, but sometimes the information is too much that my brain cant handle lol

Comment: @Daskul Also, don't forget to accept the answer if you whish to ;)